# .net capitalising Names in textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Is there a way to capitalize the first letters of a name when inputting it into the textbox?

For example, when one types john doe, the textbox should display John Doe.

I know it can be done in the c# code but just wondering if there is an easier way through attributes or regex.

Comment: may also interesting for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in the markup with CSS - ff you add the CSS attribute `text-transform` to your textbox with a value of `capitalize`, it will make the first character of each word upper case e.g.

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="NameTextBox" style="text-transform:capitalize;" />
```

No code required :-)

Comment: That's the one. I knew I've used that before :). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Shouldn't be hard to do yourself if you want, other than that there's a ToTitleCase() that would probably serve your purposes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Capitalize it using `ToTitleCase()` available in `System.Globalization Namespace`.